# Is there any other way of conversion to tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have followed this procedure:

https://kharbari.com/how-to-convert-pb-to-tflite-format/

But I face this error :

"The name 'prefix/MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'prefix/MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert', exists but only has 0 outputs."

My code is :

```
import tensorflow as tf

def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
with tf.compat.v2.io.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="prefix")
return graph


if __name__ == '__main__':
graph = load_graph('/content/123trained.pb')
for op in graph.get_operations():
    abc = graph.get_tensor_by_name(op.name + ":0")
    print(abc)
```

Can someone help me in debugging?

If there are any other procedure, please let me know!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The TF.Assert op does not have any output tensor.
However, it seems like you are trying to access it in "abc = graph.get_tensor_by_name(op.name + ":0")"